# Math Time Professional

Tags: macros, mtpro

In Math Time Professional, one needs to use

```
\ccases{}
```

instead of

```
\begin{cases} 
\end{cases}
```

in order to obtain (beautiful) curly braces. Is it possible to to use `\begin{cases} \end{cases}` as a new command and obtain `\ccases{}`?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The objective of your query isn't entirely clear. Are you asking if it's possible to emulate the beautiful curly braces produced by `\ccases{...}` with a math font other than `mtpro2`? Something else? Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico I read the question as, the OP likes the syntax of an environment, rather than a macro, so how to generate an environment that calls upon the `ccases` macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have MTPro, but I presume the approach would be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,environ}
% YOU MAY DELETE THE FOLLOWING LINE WHEN USING MTPro
\providecommand\ccases[1]{\begin{cases}#1\end{cases}}

\NewEnviron{Cases}{\ccases{\BODY}}

\begin{document}
\[
y = \begin{Cases}x_1 & \text{first choice}\\x_2& \text{second choice}\end{Cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

I use a newly defined `Cases`, so as not to obliterate the original `cases` environment.

---

**ADDENDUM**

To address a follow up question of the OP, I introduce `\Left` and `\Right` (as as not to obliterate `\left` and `\right`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,environ}
% YOU MAY DELETE THE FOLLOWING 2 LINES WHEN USING MTPro
\providecommand\ccases[1]{\begin{cases}#1\end{cases}}
\providecommand\PARENS[1]{\left(#1\right)}
%

\def\Left#1#2\Right#3{
  \ifx(#1\PARENS{#2}\else
%    \ifx[#1\BRACKETS{#2}\else% AN EXAMPLE OF HOW TO CODE MULTIPLE TESTS
      \left#1#2\right#3% USE DEFAULT IF NO ALTERNATE DEFINITION
%    \fi
  \fi
}
\NewEnviron{Cases}{\ccases{\BODY}}
\begin{document}
\[
y = 
\begin{Cases}
  \Left(\dfrac{x_1}{3}\Right) & \text{first choice}\\
  x_2& \text{second choice}
\end{Cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `\providecommand` would avoid the need to delete the line if MTPro is loaded...

Comment: Dear @Steven: Many many thanks for your solution.

Comment: Dear @Steven: Could you please tell me how I can do the same thing for \left( and \right) since in MTPro this is replaced with \PARENS{}

Comment: @MOB It is not exactly clear what you ask.  If you are saying that, in MTPro, one just uses normal parens and the size takes care of itself, then just use normal parens.  On the other hand, if you are asking, how to deal with code that is written using `\left` and `right`, without manually going in and deleting all those references, then perhaps `\let\left\relax` and `\let\right\relax` might work, by disabling their function.

Comment: What I mean is the following: I want to define a macro to get  $\left( Math \right)$ and produces  $\PARENS{Math}$

Comment: @MOB Please see my addendum.