# Redefining \left \right

Tags: macros

I have already asked a part of this question in the following post:

[Math Time Professional](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428873/math-time-professional#428873)

I fell that I am not content with the answer for this part (as I will explain why). I am using MTPro2 and to get large parenthesis or brackets one needs to use the following commands

```
  \LEFTRIGHT(){Math Formula},    \LEFTRIGHT\{\}{Math Formula}
```

I don't want to use these commands and instead I would like to use `\left(Math Formula\right)` and `\left\{ Math Formula \right\}`.  The reason being that I would like to submit my papers and many journals don't support MTPro2 so I want to use `\left(Math Formula\right)` or `\left\{ Math Formula \right\}` instead of  `\LEFTRIGHT(){Math Formula}` to prevent retyping my papers.

So now my question is, how can I define a macro that takes `\left(Math Formula\right)` and produces `\LEFTRIGHT(){Math Formula}` for me?

---

PS: As egreg suggested I can define `\providecommand\LEFTRIGHT[3]{\left#1#3\right#2}` my goal is to know how one can change the LaTeX code and redefine these comments hoping to learn more LaTeX programming.

---

Comment: Isn't it easier to define `\LEFTRIGHT` when you remove `mtpro2`?

Comment: You might be under the impression that `\left` and `\right` are LaTeX commands taking an argument (in the LaTeX sense of the word), but they aren’t: they are *primitive* commands of the underlying TeX engine.

Comment: It basically is not feasible to redefine `\left` and `\right` to support that syntax.

Comment: GuM has already pointed out that `\left` and `\right` are *primitives*.  really, all you will learn by trying to redefine them is that *it's a mistake to try to redefine a primitive*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it the other way around:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\providecommand\LEFTRIGHT[3]{\left#1#3\right#2}

\begin{document}

\[
\LEFTRIGHT(){\sum_{k=0}^n k}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you comment out the call to `mtpro2`, you get

[image]

I find neither a particularly good way to typeset the formula.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which is nice and correct, but my goal is more to learn how to redefine `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @MOB I wouldn't undertake the task even for money.